# Is it possible to extract the Text structure of a PDF with Tika and put in a JSON?

Tags: python, json, pdf, ocr, apache-tika

I would like to know if it is possible to put the texts extracted from a PDF with Tika Python in a JSON, so that in the future I can import them to the respective records of a system. So far, I've only been able to return the PDF structure (the 'metadata' in line 4), but not the text structure, which is what I need. Below is the code I'm using to return parsed text from a PDF.

```
from tika import parser

def extract_text(file):
    parsed = parser.from_file(file)
    parsed_text = parsed['metadata']
    return parsed_text

file_name_with_extension = input("Enter file name: ")
text = extract_text(file_name_with_extension)
print(text)
```

Comment: Fetch the text as HTML not plain text, then parse the html into your desired JSON structure?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I do this? @Gagravarr

Comment: See https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python#specify-output-format-to-xhtml for how to request XHTML version of the text with the Python wrapper

Comment: I got it as HTML, but now I can't get it in JSON. @Gagravarr

Comment: You will need to write some code, using something like BeautifulSoup. All depends on how you want to turn the HTML into JSON. There's no standard for that, it all depends on your business requirements